# how to set splash screen in window phone 8 Application development

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am new in Window Phone Apps Development .So I  just Want to Add Splash Screen When the application launch without using any extra Page navigation for splash screen.

Comment: Have you tried out any code?

Comment: Have you checked this example? http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Custom_splash_screen_with_progress_bar_for_Windows_Phone_applications

Comment: No actually not I am looking to do that without using pop up of splash Screen Control

Comment: you need to add an image SplashScreen.jpeg in the root folder of your project,it will be loaded till your app is ready

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769511(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi not `.jpeg` its `.jpg`

Answer (score 19):

If you want to add just single image, then create a pic in the size of `480*800` and name it as `SplashScreenImage.jpg` and put that image in the root folder.

Done! Splash Screen will be displayed on the app.

If you want to add several images with respect to the screen resolution, then create three pictures in the sizes of `480*800`, `768*1280`, and `720*1280` and name those pic as

`SplashScreenImage.screen-WVGA.jpg`,

`SplashScreenImage.screen-WXGA.jpg`,

`SplashScreenImage.screen-720p.jpg` and put these pictures in the root folder.

Done! Splash Screen will be displayed on the app with respect to phone's native screen resolution.

**NOTE:**

To modify the displaying time of SplashScreen, following code may be useful. Paste below code after `InitializeComponent();`

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

It means, the app will be activated after 2000 milli seconds. You can change as per your wish. Hope, this solves your doubt.!!

Comment: @MarioGalván you can create only in .jpg format for Windows Phone Silverlight Applications. You can create in any format for Windows Phone Runtime applications.

Comment: what for resolution 1080 x 1920 ?

Answer (score 6):

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769511(v=vs.105).aspx

From this article:

> If you’re using a single image, you should add an image file that is
> 768 × 1,280 and named SplashScreenImage.jpg to your app project. The
> phone automatically scales the image to the correct size. If you want
> to provide pixel-perfect splash screens for all resolutions, you can
> add the following images to the root folder of your app project.
>
> Resolution Dimensions in pixels File name
>
> WVGA 480 × 800 SplashScreenImage.screen-WVGA.jpg
>
> WXGA 768 × 1,280 SplashScreenImage.screen-WXGA.jpg
>
> 720p 720 x× 1,280 SplashScreenImage.screen-720p.jpg
>
> You must set the Build Action property of the image(s) to Content.
>
> Each new Windows Phone OS 7.1 project includes a SplashScreenImage.jpg
> file. To customize the splash screen, you can substitute your own
> image for the default image. You can replace the default image with
> any image you choose, but it must be 480 × 800 pixels in size, and it
> must be named SplashScreenImage.jpg. You must set the Build Action
> property of the image to Content.
>
> Windows Phone 8 apps load quickly, so a Windows Phone 8 app usually
> doesn’t need a splash screen. New Windows Phone 8 projects don’t
> include a default splash screen image file. However, if you want to
> use a splash screen in your Windows Phone 8 app, add an existing JPG
> image file to the root folder of your Windows Phone 8 project, and
> name the file SplashScreenImage.jpg.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to add a splash screen in your app, you have two options:

1. You can add a single splash screen image that the phone
   automatically scales for the three supported phone resolutions.

(If you’re using a single image, you should add an image file that is 768 × 1,280 and named SplashScreenImage.jpg to your app project. The phone automatically scales the image to the correct size)

2. If you want to provide pixel-perfect splash screens for all
   resolutions, you can add the following images to the root folder of
   your app project:

   - WVGA 480 × 800 SplashScreenImage.screen-WVGA.jpg
   - WXGA 768 × 1,280 SplashScreenImage.screen-WXGA.jpg
   - 720p 720 × 1,280 SplashScreenImage.screen-720p.jpg