# Disable hub navigationTo animation on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, controller, windows-phone-8.1

I'm new in WP and C# development and i'm kind of stuck on a detail : I'm not able to disable the hub animation launch when I navigate to a page.

On the gif below, you can see that only the hub is animated (the background of the entire hub is red).
I don't have the problem with any other controller and there is no transition nor animation assigned to the hub.

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/895824temp32024375320.gif

Someone have an clue how I can solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

according to my knowledge that animation appear only when you start your application. when you navigate pages inside the application, i didnt see any animation in my applications.

in WP8

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

in WP8.1

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), param);

or

Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

anyway, if you can modify those navigation animations with WPToolkit and Telerik. try out following link.

[Page transitions and animations in Windows Phone Runtime](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/06/24/Page-transitions-and-animations-in-Windows-Phone-Runtime.aspx)

Comment: The problem is the animation appear when I use "Frame.Navigate()". I have already tried every things from your link but this hub animation is not related with page transition.

Comment: is hub appears in your very first page now?? if so, you can add an image to splash screen.(no coding) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450446/how-to-set-splash-screen-in-window-phone-8-application-development

then that image will animate. then your page will load normally

Comment: There is no hub on my first page. I just want to navigate from hub to hub without this animation in my application.