# SplashScreenImage doesn't appear in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, splash-screen

I use VS2015 and I want to add a splash screen to the Windows Phone 8.0 app. I have added to the root directory of my project image named *SplashScreenImage.jpg* in the size of 768x1280 (also tried with 480x800) and set the Build Action property of the image to Content, as suggested here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff769511%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
and here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450446/how-to-set-splash-screen-in-window-phone-8-application-development#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450446/how-to-set-splash-screen-in-window-phone-8-application-development#_=_)

For some reason it doesn't work. After run my application on the mobile emulator via VS, splash screen doesn't appear and application starts work normally, without showing splash screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your Custom Splash Screen in Manifest File of your application.

Comment: Where and how can I do it?

Comment: Open your Manifest file (file with extension **.appxmanifest**) and go to Visual Assets Tab.Under this tab you will see the Splash Screen Option in left side.Click it and define your own splash screen their

Comment: I can't see such file http://snag.gy/rAj4w.jpg
I only see file _WMAppManifest.xml_, but there is no Visual Assets Tab.

Comment: If your project target is silverlight then you have to define your own splash screen page and then set this page in **Navigation Page** in **WMAppManifest.xml** file and write this code in your Custom Splash Screen Page constructor : `Task.Delay(2000);` and `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Your home page name", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: I created project using template **Blank App (Windows Phone)**, not **Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight)**.

Comment: Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450446/how-to-set-splash-screen-in-window-phone-8-application-development)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105323/discussion-between-saurabh-srivastava-and-darko).

Comment: "Open your Manifest file (file with extension .appxmanifest) and go to Visual Assets Tab.Under this tab you will see the Splash Screen Option in left side.Click it and define your own splash screen their " - This works in **Windows Phone 8.1** project, but I still don't know, how to set splash screen in **Windows Phone 8.0** project. But it doesn't matter anymore, I'll use 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create **Windows Phone 8.1** project instead of **Windows Phone 8.0** and follow Saurabh Srivastava's instruction from his comment under his answer:

> Open your Manifest file (file with extension .appxmanifest) and go to Visual Assets Tab.Under this tab you will see the Splash Screen Option in left side.Click it and define your own splash screen their